# Memory increase irregularly only happens on the iPhone XS Max

Tags: ios, iphone, memory-leaks

As the title, I got a memory increase. It only happens on the iPhone MS Max.
I have no idea what happen. Install the same project.
The code is same. The OS is same. Only different is the mobile device.
Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. Thanks!

I had checked the Instruments(Leaks, Allocations). I found the memory increase. But the variable is not easy to understand what happen. So, I ask it on this. Is any property of XCode for iPhone XS Max?

[Update]
Add the last image to prove there is no memory leak. All of the leak check are passed. I still have no idea why only iPhone XS Max happens. I will try to update my XCode from 11.0 to 11.1 and test it again.

[Update]
It still happens with XCode 11.1 .

Environment
Mac: 10.14.6 (18G103)
XCode: 11.0 (11A420a)
iOS: 13.1.2 (17A861)
iPhone: iPhone MS Max

The other work well.
iPhone X(iOS 13.1)
iPhone 6s(iOS 13.1)
iPhone 6s+(iOS 13.1)
iPhone 5s(iOS 12.4.1)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: Memory increase]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, I got a response from Apple.
They want me test it on 17B5077a.(iOS 13.2 beta 3)
Note all of the message I got on this.
I'll try and keep monitor it.

[image]

[Update on Oct/25/2019]
Finally, I figure out the root cause and solve it.

```
NSData *rawData = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:size]; // origin code

NSData *rawData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:size]; // new code
```

The memory will NOT be released if you use "NSData dataWithBytes:".
It only happens on arm64e(iPhone Xs/ Xs Max/ XR/ 11/ 11 pro) on iOS 13.0~13.2 beta
That means it works well before iOS 12.4 or the arm64 device(iPhone 5s/6/6+/6s/7/7+/8/X)

I share this information to the guy who has the same problem.
Hope you solve it & don't waste your time on this.